# issues converting a string to a discord.Color() object, and then back again

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The bot I'm working on for discord compiles information about a person's character, then sends a character sheet back in the form of a few embeds.

I have a lot of the functionality down, so now I'm working on flair. One of the things I wanted to do was let people change the color of the little stripe on the side of the embed, which turned out to be a lot more difficult than I thought.

I've lost track of everything I've tried to be quite honest, this has been a 5 hour issue so far, and I'm still trying random tweaks here and there.

```
    ###allows the user to set the stripe color of their character sheet embed.
@character.command(name="setcol")
async def color_set(self, ctx, *, color:str):
    if "#" in color:
        color = color.replace("#", "")
    member = ctx.message.author
    col = discord.Color(value=int(color, 16))
    await self.config.member(member).color.set(col.to_rgb())
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    col = await self.config.member(member).color()
    pvw = discord.Embed(name="Preview", description="Preview", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(*col))
    await ctx.send(embed=pvw)
    await ctx.send("{}".format(col))
```

Expected:
`##character setcol 00fe00`:
converts 00fe00 into a discord.color() object,
converts the object into a string,
saves the string in the color Config variable,
turns the string back into a discord.Color() object,
returns a preview embed with the proper color,
prints the hex code

actual:
`##character setcol 00fe00`:
converts 00fe00 into a discord.color() object,
converts the object into a string,
saves the string in the color Config variable,
returns error `TypeError: Expected int parameter, received str instead`,
function terminates

Comment: What's the full error message?  Is it your `self.config.member` calls that are failing or the Embed?  passing the color directly from the converter to the embed should work, I'm not sure why you're changing it to/from strings

Comment: When I just put the raw user input into the discord.Color() it throws an error saying that it was expecting an int, or discord.Color object, but recieved a string instead, which is why I have all the converts

Comment: With the help of the red discord bot community server, I was able to get it figured out. Had to do some wizardry to get all the variables to play nice, posting the updated code

Answer (score 1):

```
###allows the user to set the stripe color of their character sheet embed.
@character.command(name="setcol")
async def color_set(self, ctx, *, color:str):
    if "#" in color:
        color = color.replace("#", "")
    member = ctx.message.author
    col = discord.Color(value=int(color, 16))
    await self.config.member(member).color.set(col.to_rgb())
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    col = await self.config.member(member).color()
    pvw = discord.Embed(name="Preview", description="Preview", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(*col))
    await ctx.send(embed=pvw)
    await ctx.send("{}".format(col))
```

Don't know why I didn't do this in the first place instead of updating the original, but hey, whatever. SO yeah. That's the fixed code. Basically have to take the hex, drop the `#` from it, convert it to RGB, save the RGB as a tuple, convert the tuple back to RGB when its called. Its a pain, but hey, it does what I want it to!