# Is there any way to convert the hex code from string to hex colour which discord.py supports?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, discord.py, hex

I am trying to figure this out for so long,
but I am not able to convert the hex code from string to actual hex code like this `0xFFFFFF`
since discord.py doesn't take hex code in str datatype.
Code Snippet:-

```
@client.command()
async def testing(ctx):
    # color = lgd.hexConvertor(colorCollection.find({},{"_id":0,"Hex":1}))
    c = "0xFFFFFF"
    inte = int(c,16)
    color = hex(inte)
    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = "testing",color = color))
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 221, in testing
    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = "testing",color = color))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/embeds.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.colour = colour
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/embeds.py", line 230, in colour
    raise TypeError('Expected discord.Colour, int, or Embed.Empty but received %s instead.' % value.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Expected discord.Colour, int, or Embed.Empty but received str instead.
```

This is how I stored the hex codes in my mongodb atlas database->
[image: mongodb hex codes]

Edit:-
It worked on using `inte` instead of color

Comment: Does this answer your question? [issues converting a string to a discord.Color() object, and then back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53926825/issues-converting-a-string-to-a-discord-color-object-and-then-back-again)

Comment: @AbhinavMathur it worked!
I didn't knew that it would work

Comment: @Armaan added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error.

```
TypeError: Expected discord.Colour, int, or Embed.Empty
```

An `int` would suffice, no need for extra conversions.

```py
@client.command()
async def testing(ctx):
    # color = lgd.hexConvertor(colorCollection.find({},{"_id":0,"Hex":1}))
    c = "0xFFFFFF"
    int_colour = int(c,16)
    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = "testing",color = int_colour))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> color = "0xFFFFFF"
>>> int_color = int(color,16)
>>> hex(int_color)
'0xffffff'
>>> # basically the same thing
>>>
>>> from discord import Color
>>>
>>> Color(int_color)
<Colour value=16777215>
>>> #just ints work
```

[discord.py documentation for colours](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Colour)

Comment: this is not straight forward tho idk what you are trying to show but it worked on using just `inte`

Comment: yeah it was a bit much xD ig the teal part was using disc.py teal hex to show it does work I'll prolly edit it out

Answer (score 0):

This is a list of a lot of colors with the codes that discord.py supports

```
default = 0
teal = 0x1abc9c
dark_teal = 0x11806a
green = 0x2ecc71
dark_green = 0x1f8b4c
blue = 0x3498db
dark_blue = 0x206694
purple = 0x9b59b6
dark_purple = 0x71368a
magenta = 0xe91e63
dark_magenta = 0xad1457
gold = 0xf1c40f
dark_gold = 0xc27c0e
orange = 0xe67e22
dark_orange = 0xa84300
red = 0xe74c3c
dark_red = 0x992d22
lighter_grey = 0x95a5a6
dark_grey = 0x607d8b
light_grey = 0x979c9f
darker_grey = 0x546e7a
blurple = 0x7289da
greyple = 0x99aab5
```

Comment: I already made a whole database for that but the reason for my question was to fetch the hex code from string